# How to use/install Command 'host' Docker Alpine3.8

Tags: docker, host, alpine-linux

I have to use the 'host' commmand in a java programm.
It works locally on my Linux Ubuntu but when running on Docker Alpine3.8 image it does not work.
So, I think I should add/install this tool.
I tried to install dnsutils but it doesnt work !
Am I wrong about the syntax or something else ?

My use-case : run this command on my java programm

```
host 66.249.66.1
1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.
```

Thanks for your replies

Comment: how do you run it and what error message do you get? Alpine3.8 probably does not have the binary. What is the error when you try to install it?

Answer (score 5):

Alpine has a website called pkgs.alpinelinux.org to find the package name for a given file. In Alpine 3.8, the package that has the `host` command is [bind-tools](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=host&path=&name=&branch=v3.8&arch=x86_64).

Answer (score 0):

So, Finally I did it but directly in my java programm using this code :

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("IP");
```